# Change value by group based in reference within group

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, dplyr

given a table with defined groups where within each group
I have just 1 reference (query) I'd like to change all values of a column
based in value of the reference.
This values are just 1 or -1.

The idea is:
- if reference is equal to 1 so keep all values as it are
- but if reference is -1, so all values should be multiplied by -1, so that way reference became to be 1 and the items with value 1 became to be -1
- Also, modified groups should have opposite order

I'm trying to do this way:

```
library(tidyverse)
item <- c("a", "b", "c",  "d", "e", "f", "g",  "h", "i",  "j",  "k",  "l")
grou <- c(1, 1, 1,  2, 2, 2, 3,  3, 3,  4,  4,  4)
quer <- c(0, 1, 0,  0, 1, 0, 0,  1, 0,  0,  1,  0)
dir  <- c(1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1)
ds <- tibble(item      = item,
                 group     = grou,
                 query     = quer,
                 direction = dir)
ds %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate( 
    direction = ifelse( 
      direction[query == 1] == 1, direction, (-1 * direction)  
    ) 
  )
```

So this

```
# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   group [4]
   item  group query direction 
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> 
 1 a         1     0         1 
 2 b         1     1         1 
 3 c         1     0         1 
 4 d         2     0        -1 
 5 e         2     1         1 
 6 f         2     0         1 
 7 g         3     0         1 
 8 h         3     1        -1 
 9 i         3     0         1 
10 j         4     0        -1 
11 k         4     1        -1 
12 l         4     0        -1
```

Should became this

```
# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   group [4]
   item  group query direction 
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> 
 1 a         1     0         1 
 2 b         1     1         1 
 3 c         1     0         1 
 4 d         2     0        -1 
 5 e         2     1         1 
 6 f         2     0         1 
 7 i         3     0        -1 
 8 h         3     1         1 
 9 g         3     0        -1 
10 l         4     0         1 
11 k         4     1         1 
12 j         4     0         1
```

But it is not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: @markus I added the example, and fix the direction (I forgot in last edit)

Comment: @SvenHohenstein no, the output seems nice. The values only should be changed if `query == 1` is `direction == 1`. So its strictly depends of `direction` value of `query == 1` by group, if its not all elements within the group must to be as it are.

Comment: It seems like you probably want case_when in your mutate, but I don't understand the logic enough to write this out. What is the group_by supposed to be achieving here?

Comment: @EmilyKothe it should archiving the `group` column.

Comment: @AurelianoGuedes I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "archiving" in this context.

Comment: @EmilyKothe means group by `group` column. I think I did. ```ds %>% 
  left_join(
    ds %>% 
      filter(query == 1) %>%
      select( group, direction) %>%
      rename(factor = direction), 
    by = "group"
  ) %>%
  mutate( direction = direction * factor) %>%
  group_by(group, factor) %>%
  arrange(ifelse( factor == 1, item, rev(item))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(group) %>%
  select(-factor)```

Comment: @AurelianoGuedes in the code you provided you get the same result without the group_by `ds %>% left_join( ds %>% filter(query == 1) %>% select( group, direction) %>% rename(factor = direction), by = "group" ) %>% mutate( direction = direction * factor) %>% arrange(ifelse( factor == 1, item, rev(item))) %>% arrange(group) %>% select(-factor)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```
ds %>%
  rowid_to_column("id") %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(tmp = max(query * direction) - 0.5,
         direction = tmp * 2 * direction) %>%
  arrange(id * tmp, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  select(-c(id, tmp))
```

The result:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   group [4]
   item  group query direction
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 a         1     0         1
 2 b         1     1         1
 3 c         1     0         1
 4 d         2     0        -1
 5 e         2     1         1
 6 f         2     0         1
 7 i         3     0        -1
 8 h         3     1         1
 9 g         3     0        -1
10 l         4     0         1
11 k         4     1         1
12 j         4     0         1
```

Comment: Hi Sven! It is also need to reverse the order for item so I suggest this: 
`ds %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(direction2 = (max(query * direction) - 0.5) * 2 * direction,
         item2 =ifelse((max(query * direction) - 0.5) * 2 * direction!=direction, rev(item), item))`

Comment: I did this way but I didn't reverse the modified groups ```ds %>% 
  left_join(
    ds %>% 
      filter(query == 1) %>%
      select( group, direction) %>%
      rename(factor = direction), 
    by = "group"
  ) %>%
  mutate( direction = direction * factor) %>%
  select(-factor)```

Comment: EDIT: ```ds %>% 
  left_join(
    ds %>% 
      filter(query == 1) %>%
      select( group, direction) %>%
      rename(factor = direction), 
    by = "group"
  ) %>%
  mutate( direction = direction * factor) %>%
  group_by(group, factor) %>%
  arrange(ifelse( factor == 1, item, rev(item))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(group) %>%
  select(-factor)```

Comment: @AurelianoGuedes See the update of my answer. Now the row order within the affected groups is reversed.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein seems your solution work better than mine, since my solution don't handle well with all cases. Thanks you.